# How to assign task name in Spring TaskExecutor and check if it is still alive?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, concurrency

Lest's consider that I have the following:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //do something expensive
    }
}

public class ThreadExecutor {

      private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    public ThreadExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    public void fireThread(){
        taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable());
    }
}
```

my xml is the following:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>

<bean id="threadExecutor" class="com.vanilla.threads.controllers.ThreadExecutor">
    <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

in my Spring MVC controller I start the task:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/startTask.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        threadExecutor.fireThread();
    return mv;
    }
```

Now let's consider that I would like to create another request(`@RequestMapping(value="/checkStatus.html"`) which will tell if the the task started in my previous Request has been finished.

So my questions are simple:

1) Can I assign name to the task in TaskExecutor and if yes, how can I do it?

2) How can I check that the task with that specific name has been done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, but..

Instead of using `taskExecutor.execute()` use `taskExecutor.submit()` which returns a `Future`.   Put the `Future` in the `HttpSession`, and when a checkStatus request comes in, pull the `Future` from the session and call `isDone()` on it.   If you need to give it a name then instead of putting the `Future` in the session directly have a `Map<String, Future>` in the session where the key is the name of your task.